# In Elasticsearch, is possible to cluster documents that share the most similar texts, without giving an initial query to compare to?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, text-analysis

In Elasticsearch, is possible to group documents that share the most similar texts, without giving an initial query to compare to?

I know is possible to query and get "more like this document" but, is possible to cluster documents within an index according to a field values?

For instance:

document 1: **The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**

document 2: **Barcelona is a great city**

document 3: **The fast orange fox jumps over the lazy dog**

document 4: **Madrid is a great city**

document 5: **I do not like to eat fish**

Now, perform some kind of aggregation that, without giving a search query, it can group:

**Group 1**: document 1 and document 3

**Group 2**: document 2 and document 4

**Group 3**: document 5

I will really appreciate any clue!

Comment: What interface would you expect? An enumeration over the groups? In any case, you would have to iterate over all groups. So you could just iterate over all documents, query for similar documents, keep a list of already retrieved documents and then don't query for those documents that have already been returned.

Comment: Well, i think that iterate over all docs could be expensive. I can query all docs before index a new one and build the groups dynamically using the results from the queries. I was looking a solution for an already indexed set of docs. Thanks a lot for your comment Joe.